# radiobutton to display modal popup on click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Am working on a small project to get familiar with ASP.NET.
I have this model

```
public partial class COUNTRIES
{
public int COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string COUNTRY_NAME { get; set; }
public int COUNTRY_AREA { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COUNTRY_NAME, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.COUNTRY_NAME, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.COUNTRY_AREA, 1, new { id = "", value = "" }) North East
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.COUNTRY_AREA, 2, new { id = "", value = "" }) North West
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.COUNTRY_AREA, 3, new { id = "", value = "" }) South West
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.COUNTRY_AREA, 4, new { id = "", value = "" }) South East
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**m => m.COUNTRY_AREA** should generate 4 radio buttons, and the 4 radio buttons are tied to it.

What I want to achieve is that When I click on:

1. RadioButton 1 , it should display a popup modal form with message "You are from North East.
2. RadioButton 2 , it should display a popup modal form with message "You are from North West.
3. RadioButton 3 , it should display a popup modal form with message "You are from South East.
4. RadioButton 1 , it should display a popup modal form with message "You are from South East.

How do I go about it

Comment: You can easily accomplish that using javascript...can you add to your question, the rendered html for one radio button?

Answer (score 0):

This will work, and it is factored so that there is only one JavaScript function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index706</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".DoPopup").click(function (event) {
                alert("You are from the " + event.target.id);
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COUNTRY_NAME, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.COUNTRY_NAME, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.COUNTRY_AREA, 1, new { @class = "DoPopup", id = "North East", value = "" }) North East
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.COUNTRY_AREA, 2, new { @class = "DoPopup", id = "North West", value = "" }) North West
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.COUNTRY_AREA, 3, new { @class = "DoPopup", id = "South West", value = "" }) South West
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.COUNTRY_AREA, 4, new { @class = "DoPopup", id = "South East", value = "" }) South East
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```